# Unable to reduce a list of booleans in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to map to boolean and reduce in kotlin. This is my code

```
class Model{
 fun isEmpty() : Boolean
}


list.asSequence().map { model ->
      {
        model.isEmpty()
      }
     }.reduce { acc, next -> (acc && next)}
```

But compiler gives me an error telling

```
Type mismatch required () Boolean? but found Boolean
```

What am I doing wrong? I hope I am not doing anything conceptually wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't Kotlin's lambda syntax.

Kotlin lambdas are *entirely* contained within `{}`, i.e.:

```
{
    arg1, ..., argn ->
    [ lambda body ]
    [ last statement (implicitly returned) ]
}
```

By doing

```
list.asSequence().map { model ->
    {
        model.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

You are making a lambda that *returns* another lambda of type `() -> Boolean`:

```
{
    model.isEmpty()
}
```

So the real type of this lambda is `(Model) -> () -> Boolean`.

Remove the inner brackets:

```
list.asSequence().map { model -> model.isEmpty() }.reduce { acc, next -> acc && next }
```

Additionally, single-parameter lambdas have an implicit parameter name `it`, so you could just write:

```
list.asSequence().map { it.isEmpty() }.reduce { acc, next -> acc && next }
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to check if an entire list is empty. I believe you can simply write:

```
list.all { it.isEmpty() }
```

or use a method reference:

```
list.all(Model::isEmpty)
```

though that's up to personal preference.